# What is the field of 2 elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

I am trying to solve this question:

Show that the ring M2(F2) of 2×2 matrices with entries from F2 is non-commutative. Here F2 is the ﬁeld of 2 elements

Using a counterexample I can easily show that the ring M2(R) is non-commutative.
I assume this question can be done in a similar way. However I am unsure on what the elements of the 2x2 matrix should be. In other words, what is the field of 2 elements?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2$ is just the field that only consists of the elements $0,1$. Addition is defined as $0+0 = 1+1 = 0, 1+0 = 0+1=1$ and multiplication is defined as $0\cdot 0 = 0\cdot 1 = 1\cdot 0 = 0, 1\cdot 1 = 1$. You can check that it satisfies all the field axioms.

Comment: So If I let the matrix A and B be 2x2 matrices, where the (1,1)-entry of A is 1 and all the other entries are 0, and the (1,2)-entry of B is 1 with all the other entries 0. Ofcouse AB is not equal to BA therefore would this counterexample be sufficient enough?

Comment: The aditional requirement that elements are in $F_2$ is a little perverse, as it plays no role in the proof: if you use the matrices $A=\left(\begin{matrix}0 &1\\1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{matrix}1 &1\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$, you will find that multiplying $B$ by $A$ on the left swaps rows, whereas multiplying on the right swaps columns, and there is no operation giving a result not in $\{0,1\}$, in any field.

Comment: So the matrix examples I gave would not work?

Comment: user544158: Yes, that is a good counterexample that works in any field. The one @Jean-ClaudeArbaut gave has the additional advantage that the matrices are invertible, so it _also_ shows that the _group_ $GL(2,F)$ is non-abelian for every field $F$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the field consisting only of $0$ and $1$, with the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ modulo $2$, so $1+1=0$ in this field.

Comment: So If I let the matrix A and B be 2x2 matrices, where the (1,1)-entry of A is 1 and all the other entries are 0, and the (1,2)-entry of B is 1 with all the other entries 0. Ofcourse AB is not equal to BA therefore would this counterexample be sufficient enough?

Answer (score 0):

The field of 2 elements is $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},$ i.e. it's a [residue field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_field). Equipped with the operations $+$ and $\cdot$, it only has the additive unit 0 and the multiplicative unit 1 as elements.